# Codeigniter get inactive users on ci ion auth

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter ion auth from [benedmunds](http://benedmunds.com/ion_auth/).

how can we get all inactive user ?

I know to get all users, we can use

```
$this->ion_auth->users()->result();
```

But, I want to filter to retrieve only inactive users

Comment: I'm guessing something like: `$this->ion_auth->users()->where('active', '0')->result();`. Looking at the source code, it seems that the [where()](https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth/blob/2/models/Ion_auth_model.php#L1275) function is fine.

Comment: Thanks for reply @PXgamer.  Not work, still showing all users

Answer (score 2):

I have contacted the owner library, https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth/issues/1121

use this code:

```
$this->ion_auth->where('users.active', 0)->users()->result();
```